# Dynamic width of textctrl in frame

Tags: wxpython

I have a basic frame containing three widgets in a flexgridsizer(3, 1). A title label, a textctrl, and a button. The textctrl is populated from a test.txt file, the contents of which are undefined but will generally be of a fixed width. (Normally 80 or 120 chars).

I'd like to have the panel automatically create at an appropriate width to perfectly contain the text, but at the moment it doesn't look quite right (there's no border on the left but there's a noticeable whitespace/gap on the right between the end of the text and the scrollbar).

My questions are these:

1. Is there a nicer way to have wx automatically calculate the desired width of the frame and apply it depending on the contained text? I have looked at all of the GetSize, GetBestSize, GetClientSize, GetVirtualSize etc functions and none return values close to what I'd call correct (those returned by the DC method).
2. The width of the scroll bar returned by SystemSettings.GetMetric is way off. It returns 15px but it's only actually about 3 in reality (running on Ubuntu 14.04). This is half of the reason I think it looks off to me. Is this the right way to get the width of the scrollbar or is there a better way?

Also any other advice on how to clean this up would be much appreciated. Below are sample bits of the code and text file.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.stattext as ST

class TextFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, style = wx.STAY_ON_TOP)

        self.lbl_title = ST.GenStaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, "What's Changed?", style = wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.txt_changes = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "", style = wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.btn_ok = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK, "OK")
        self.btn_ok.SetDefault()

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOK, self.btn_ok)


    def __set_properties(self):
        font = self.txt_changes.GetFont()
        font = wx.Font(font.GetPointSize(),
                       wx.TELETYPE,
                       font.GetStyle(),
                       font.GetWeight(),
                       font.GetUnderlined())

        self.txt_changes.SetFont(font)

        self.txt_changes.SetValue(open("test.txt", "r").read())

        self.btn_ok.SetFocus()


    def __do_layout(self):
        sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(3, 1, 0, 0)
        sizer.AddGrowableCol(0)
        sizer.AddGrowableRow(1)

        sizer.Add(self.lbl_title, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizer.Add(self.txt_changes, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizer.Add(self.btn_ok, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        # Dynamically calculate the width of text and use it to set the width of the frame.
        dc = wx.ScreenDC()
        dc.SetFont(self.txt_changes.GetFont())
        w = dc.GetMultiLineTextExtent(self.txt_changes.GetValue())[:1]
        w = (w[0] + wx.SystemSettings.GetMetric(wx.SYS_VSCROLL_X))
        size = self.GetSize()
        size = (w, size[1])
        self.SetSize(size)

        self.Layout()
        self.CenterOnScreen()


    def OnOK(self, event):
        self.Destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    t = TextFrame(None, -1)
    t.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

This is some crap content for test.txt:

```
================================================================================
================================================================================
================================================================================
fsdaeryw5etyiuoht oyt934y tq43eyt 9p3qy4 5p93qy tqp983y4 tpq38ytp9y3 tpq t  q34t
 34qo p394yt 93qpy 5q3p94yt erig r gye  tyepy tpyt paytpey4 tpe ytae ytpa4 twa 
================================================================================
================================================================================
================================================================================
fsdaeryw5etyiuoht oyt934y tq43eyt 9p3qy4 5p93qy tqp983y4 tpq38ytp9y3 tpq t  q34t
 34qo p394yt 93qpy 5q3p94yt erig r gye  tyepy tpyt paytpey4 tpe ytae ytpa4 twa 
================================================================================
================================================================================
================================================================================
fsdaeryw5etyiuoht oyt934y tq43eyt 9p3qy4 5p93qy tqp983y4 tpq38ytp9y3 tpq t  q34t
 34qo p394yt 93qpy 5q3p94yt erig r gye  tyepy tpyt paytpey4 tpe ytae ytpa4 twa 
================================================================================
================================================================================
================================================================================
fsdaeryw5etyiuoht oyt934y tq43eyt 9p3qy4 5p93qy tqp983y4 tpq38ytp9y3 tpq t  q34t
 34qo p394yt 93qpy 5q3p94yt erig r gye  tyepy tpyt paytpey4 tpe ytae ytpa4 twa 
================================================================================
================================================================================
================================================================================
fsdaeryw5etyiuoht oyt934y tq43eyt 9p3qy4 5p93qy tqp983y4 tpq38ytp9y3 tpq t  q34t
 34qo p394yt 93qpy 5q3p94yt erig r gye  tyepy tpyt paytpey4 tpe ytae ytpa4 twa 
================================================================================
================================================================================
================================================================================
fsdaeryw5etyiuoht oyt934y tq43eyt 9p3qy4 5p93qy tqp983y4 tpq38ytp9y3 tpq t  q34t
 34qo p394yt 93qpy 5q3p94yt erig r gye  tyepy tpyt paytpey4 tpe ytae ytpa4 twa 
================================================================================
================================================================================
================================================================================
fsdaeryw5etyiuoht oyt934y tq43eyt 9p3qy4 5p93qy tqp983y4 tpq38ytp9y3 tpq t  q34t
 34qo p394yt 93qpy 5q3p94yt erig r gye  tyepy tpyt paytpey4 tpe ytae ytpa4 twa 
================================================================================
================================================================================
================================================================================
fsdaeryw5etyiuoht oyt934y tq43eyt 9p3qy4 5p93qy tqp983y4 tpq38ytp9y3 tpq t  q34t
 34qo p394yt 93qpy 5q3p94yt erig r gye  tyepy tpyt paytpey4 tpe ytae ytpa4 twa
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.stattext as ST

class TextFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, style = wx.STAY_ON_TOP)

        self.lbl_title = ST.GenStaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, "What's Changed?", style = wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.txt_changes = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "", style = wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.btn_ok = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK, "OK")
        self.btn_ok.SetDefault()

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOK, self.btn_ok)


    def __set_properties(self):
        font = self.txt_changes.GetFont()
        font = wx.Font(font.GetPointSize(),
                       wx.TELETYPE,
                       font.GetStyle(),
                       font.GetWeight(),
                       font.GetUnderlined())

        self.txt_changes.SetFont(font)

        tv = open("test.txt", "r")

        # dynamic sizing
        l1 = tv.readline()
        tv.seek(0) # reset to beginning of file
        lw = self.txt_changes.GetTextExtent(l1)
        # on Windows this is 17
        scw = wx.SystemSettings.GetMetric(wx.SYS_VSCROLL_X)
        # still need to adjust, I think it is the small border
        scw += 2 
        self.SetBestFittingSize((lw[0] + scw, self.GetSize()[1]))

        self.txt_changes.SetValue(tv.read())

        self.btn_ok.SetFocus()


    def __do_layout(self):
        sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(0, 1, 0, 0)
        sizer.AddGrowableCol(0)
        sizer.AddGrowableRow(1)

        sizer.Add(self.lbl_title, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizer.Add(self.txt_changes, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizer.Add(self.btn_ok, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.Layout()
        self.CenterOnScreen()


    def OnOK(self, event):
        self.Destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    t = TextFrame(None, -1)
    t.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: That seems to have a larger gap on the right-hand side now and seems to hard-specify an added pixel width, which I was trying to avoid. I was hoping for as much as possible to be calculated dynamically. :)

Comment: A bit better, sorry still need to adjust it by 2 which I think is the border, don't know how to get that.